# List of java bean vs List of hashmap

Tags: java, performance, csv, hashmap, pojo

I am working on a module where i need to parse a csv file, pick a few fields from it and process those fields to persist in my database.

What i am doing is, using OpenCSV i have read the file into **List<String[]>**. Then i loop on this List to map csv data and prepare a list of hashmap(**List<Map<String, String>>**) which serves as my final request.

We know that hashmap has performance overheads and creating a list of hashmap doesn't seem right to me from performance perspective. I have read using java beans is much more efficient. So i want to know the best approach.

When i use a hashmap in request, i am able to validate my request data(for null/blank data checks) using the below code which is quite generic and without any hardcoded methods works for all request data.

```
public static boolean validateDataValues(final Map<String, String> data, final List<String> keys) {
    for (String key : keys) {
      if (StringUtils.isBlank(data.get(key))) {// checks for both null and empty strings
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Also using a hashmap allows me to carry additional data in request which might not be part of csv. If i use java bean in its place, i'll have to call getter of each mandatory field for validation. So while coding should i consider the performance factor with java beans or the less code factor that is there with hashmap.

Please suggest what might be the best approach on this.

Comment: I have never heard that HashMap has performance overheads.

Comment: The best approach in this particular case is the Most Readable approach.

Comment: Using objects is more efficient than using HashMap though I would make sure you know you have a performance problem before changing it.  Note: using a custom object can also help with type validation.

Comment: I am aware that the difference in java bean and hashmap efficiency is negligible considering todays enhanced hardware but since i was creating a list of new hashmap objects and count of that may be in some hundreds depending on data of CSV so i just wanted to make sure i follow the right path from the start.

Comment: Your choice of data structure should depend on the functions you need to perform on data. If you need to search your list or sort it or etc. Hashmaps have high performance for searching. If you want a sorted list of data, there are better data structures. So what is your major operation? (insert/delete/search)

Comment: Couple of hundred objects creation are nothing for the modern hardware. Even millions of objects.